# Dividing polynomial fractions with varying term quantities

Tags: polynomials, fractions

I'm working through an old algebra book as a refresher and I've come across what should be a simple polynomial division. The exercise prompts the reader to perform the following operation:

$$
\frac{a^2-9}{a^2+3a} \div \frac{a-3}{4}
$$

I started off by inverting the $\div$ sign by instead multiplying by the reciprocal which results in:

$$
\frac{a^2-9}{a^2+3a} \cdot \frac{4}{a-3}
$$

I spent nearly 2 hours at this point trying everything my mind could conjure in terms of factoring, simplifying, and multiplying, but none of my attempts ever arrived at the listed answer:

$$
\frac{4}{a}
$$

If someone could help me through the steps required to solve this, you'll have taught a man to fish.

**Solution from below:**
$$
\frac{a^2-9}{a^2+3a} \cdot \frac{4}{a-3}=\frac{4(a-3)(a+3)}{a(a+3)(a-3)}=\frac{4}{a}
$$

I had not factored $a^2 + 3a$ to $a(a+3)$ correctly in any of my attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $$\frac{a^2-9}{a^2+3a} \cdot \frac{4}{a-3}=\frac{4(a-3)(a+3)}{a(a+3)(a-3)}=\frac{4}{a}
$$

Comment: Ah, messed up the dreaded factoring. Hopefully I'll get my algebra chops up to that level soon :).  Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

note that $$a^2-9=(a-3)(a+3)$$
$$a^2+3a=a(a+3)$$

Comment: Thank you sir.  Michael beat you to it by seconds, but I appreciate the reply nonetheless.